# Fail remaining pytest tests if a specific one fails

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

So I have a directory filled with a bunch of tests written in python with the proper syntax to make sure they run in order.

So let's say I have a test which if fails, currently calls pytest.exit('Exit Message'). The problem with this is that the generated test output in XML only records the tests preceding it. I would prefer that the whole suite is run but are reported as failed if the test mentioned above fails.

A solution I thought of was setting an environment variable in case it fails and then checking that environment variable in the following tests. The issue is that running it with Jenkins, the environment variable set isn't detected and I would prefer a native solution if it exists.

What I have is:

```
def test_check_connection(self):
    ...
    if Failed:
        pytest.exit('No connectivity')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pytest: how to skip the rest of tests in the class if one has failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411431/pytest-how-to-skip-the-rest-of-tests-in-the-class-if-one-has-failed)

Comment: have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly. If you want `pytest` to stop after the first failing test case use the `-x` option

```
pytest -x ...
```

If you want to run all tests and want to know if there were any failures from jenkins check the exit code of the pytest app:

> Running pytest can result in six different exit codes:
>
> Exit code 0:  All tests were collected and passed successfully
>
> Exit code 1:  Tests were collected and run but some of the tests failed
>
> Exit code 2:  Test execution was interrupted by the user
>
> Exit code 3:  Internal error happened while executing tests
>
> Exit code 4:  pytest command line usage error
>
> Exit code 5:  No tests were collected

Comment: When I use pytest -x option pytest stops at the first occurrence of a test failure? For eg: I've many "pytest.fail"  but would like to continue the test irrespective of the failure. But when I have trouble logging to application I want to quit and not run remaining tests. Can I use pytest -x option for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a global variable in a test and referencing it in a later test like so:

```py
def test_check_connection(self):
    ...
    if Failed:
        global failed_conn_check = True
    else:
        global failed_conn_check = False
```

Then at the end of the tests:

```py
    ...
    if failed_conn_check:
        raise SomeException
    ...
```