# Pytest - skip (xfail) mixed with parametrize

Tags: pytest, skip

is there a way to use the @incremental plugin like described att [Pytest: how to skip the rest of tests in the class if one has failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411431/pytest-how-to-skip-the-rest-of-tests-in-the-class-if-one-has-failed/12579625#12579625][1]) mixed with @pytest.mark.parametrize like below:

```
@pytest.mark.incremental
Class TestClass:
  @pytest.mark.parametrize("input", data)
  def test_preprocess_check(self,input):
    # prerequisite for test

  @pytest.mark.parametrize("input",data)
  def test_process_check(self,input):
    # test only if test_preprocess_check succeed
```

The problem i encountered is, at the first fail of **test_preprocess_check** with a given input of my data set, the following *test_preprocess_check* and *test_process_check* are labeled "xfail". 
The behaviour i expect will be, at each new "input" of my parametrized data set, the test will act in an incremental fashion.

ex: data = [0,1,2]

if only *test_preprocess_check*(0) failed:

i got the following report:
    1 failed, 5 xfailed

but i expect the report:
    1 failed, 1 xfailed, 4 passed

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experiments i found a way to generalize the @incremental to works with *parametrize* annotation. Simply rewrite the *_previousfailed* argument to make it unique for each input. The argument *_genid* was excactly the need.

I added a @pytest.mark.incrementalparam to achieve this.

Code become:

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):

    previousfailed_attr = getattr(item, "_genid",None)
    if previousfailed_attr is not None:
        previousfailed = getattr(item.parent, previousfailed_attr, None)
        if previousfailed is not None:
            pytest.xfail("previous test failed (%s)" %previousfailed.name)

    previousfailed = getattr(item.parent, "_previousfailed", None)
    if previousfailed is not None:
        pytest.xfail("previous test failed (%s)" %previousfailed.name)

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call): 

    if "incrementalparam" in item.keywords: 
        if call.excinfo is not None:
            previousfailed_attr = item._genid
            setattr(item.parent,previousfailed_attr, item)

    if "incremental" in item.keywords:
        if call.excinfo is not None:
            parent = item.parent
            parent._previousfailed = item
```

It's interesting to mention that's it can't be used without parametrize cause parametrize annotation creates automatically _genid variable.

Hope this can helps others than me.

Comment: take care that _genid is composed of your "input" data set, and thus could lead to invalid variable name, mapping it to a 100% valid variable name could avoid some problems