# pytest skip other suite's tests due to specific critical test failure

Tags: testing, pytest, infrastructure

I want to build an infrastructure which allows to wrap **a code section in a test**, or to wrap **the whole test function**, to mark that this code/test is critical for the other rest tests in the suit.

And in case that this wrapped critical code fails, **skip the rest of the tests in the same suite**.

I can do it with context-manager and fixures, but I wonder if can do it in a more elegant way, maybe a PYTEST plugin or with some other PYTEST tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pytest: how to skip the rest of tests in the class if one has failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411431/pytest-how-to-skip-the-rest-of-tests-in-the-class-if-one-has-failed)